# angular group by while iterating records on select list

Tags: angularjs

Let's say if I've data coming in JSON like this.

```
[
{
"id": 10,
"session": "test2",
"event": "Event 2"
},
{
"id": 11,
"session": "TEST 22",
"event": "Event 2"
},
{
"id": 9,
"session": "test 1",
"event": "Event 1"
}
]
```

I want to group the records by event, (Event 2 is repeated) and display a select box while keeping track of the id (on $scope so I can update the form).

Expectation.

```
<select>
  <optgroup label="Event 1">
      <option value="10">test2</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Event 2">
       <option value="11">Test 22</option>
       <option value="9">test 1</option>
   </optgroup>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ng-options="opt.id as opt.session group by opt.event for opt in options"
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, another question, what variable is available on the scope as the selected id from the drop down menu?

Comment: put ng-model in select, this varible is selected value on select